# How do you wait a little before drawing a Path on the Canvas?

Tags: java, android, canvas

I have a wave that moves according to the amplitude that the speaker is currently picking up, but if I'm quiet and then make a sudden noise, the wave "jumps" to that amplitude immediately, and I want to make the effect slightly more gradual. How can I accomplish this task?

I'm drawing the wave now using:

```
Canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
path.reset();
invalidate();
```

All in the `onDraw` method of my custom `View`. So the path is essentially drawn with whatever amplitude the mic is currently picking up (with a limit), which means that if the amplitude picked up is at say 100 right now then suddenly jumps to say 4000, the path will "jump" considerably as well.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on actually what you need to do. If you want to smooth your path, i suggest you to draw a curve instead a path with some angle (you also can make with lines). 
Otherwise, you can do the same using sleeps regarding that the whole transition should be small enought to fit into the frequency  that you collect data.

Comment: I'm actually using a curve to draw the path. The problem isn't that the actual path looks bad, it's that sometimes one path has a low amplitude and the next millisecond it has a very high amplitude, so the path jumps from one position to the next very quickly. Can you elaborate more on the sleep and possibly provide code?

Comment: Sorry i had not understood properly. Why don't you use concepts as the variance of the signal in order to smooth  increases or decreases? Thus the changes would be softer. So instead of adding or decreasing the new difference you will reduce it by some rate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think adding sleeps would be be best solution, as you could possibly loose incoming data that you may want to graph.  I'd suggest saving the last x samples and then averaging in the incoming packets.  So if you're at 10 and the next few samples come in at 4000 and then back down, your average would be not nearly has high.  If it rose to 4000  and stayed there, the graph would eventually rise to 4000 in a few samples, depending on how you are averaging.